# Good introduction to Benjamini- Schramm limits

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, graph-theory

So I was wondering if someone might be able to suggest a good intro paper/ article for getting a feel for Benjamini- Schramm limits as well as getting a sense of the kinds of results that people have been able to get so far.

Comment: It would help if you could say what kind of things you're broadly interested in.